# npm Conflicting peer dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

The following error only occurs on Azure DevOps build pipeline but not on my localhost:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @wtw/chart@1.3.0
npm ERR! Found: @wtw/common@1.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@wtw/common
npm ERR!   @wtw/common@"1.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @wtw/common@"^0.0.0" from @wtw/chart@1.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@wtw/chart
npm ERR!   @wtw/chart@"1.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @wtw/common@0.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@wtw/common
npm ERR!   peer @wtw/common@"^0.0.0" from @wtw/chart@1.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@wtw/chart
npm ERR!     @wtw/chart@"1.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I tried moving to @wtw/common@0.0.0 on my package.json, but then got:.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: client-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@12.2.16
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~12.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^8.1.0" from @wtw/common@0.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@wtw/common
npm ERR!   @wtw/common@"0.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\sveAzRCSBLD\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sveAzRCSBLD\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-21T15_22_38_499Z-debug-0.log
```

I do not control the code of @wtw/common so I cannot change it's package.json.

My package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~12.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@grapecity/wijmo.angular2.all": "~5.20203.766",
    "@grapecity/wijmo.grid": "~5.20203.766",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "~6.0.1",
    "@ngrx/data": "12.5.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "~12.5.1",
    "@ngrx/entity": "~12.5.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "12.5.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "~10.1.2",
    "@wtw/angularkit": "~1.3.0",
    "@wtw/canvas": "0.1.1",
    "@wtw/chart": "1.3.0",
    "@wtw/common": "1.4.0",
    "@wtw/data-table": "1.3.0",
    "@wtw/filter": "1.2.0",
    "@wtw/horizontal-menu": "1.3.0",
    "@wtw/map": "1.2.0",
    "@wtw/qa": "2.5.0",
    "@wtw/reports": "2.3.0",
    "angular-plotly.js": "~3.0.0",
    "angular-resize-event": "~2.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "~4.3.1",
    "dompurify": "~2.0.17",
    "highcharts": "~9.0.0",
    "highcharts-angular": "~2.8.2",
    "jsonpath-plus": "~4.0.0",
    "moment": "~2.29.1",
    "ng-in-viewport": "~6.0.3",
    "ngrx-store-localstorage": "~12.0.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "~6.1.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "~14.2.1",
    "ol": "6.1.1",
    "plotly.js-dist": "~1.54.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "subsink": "~1.0.1",
    "tslib": "~2.3.0",
    "vm": "~0.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

How to resolve the error at the beginning of this post?

Answer (score 0):

In the azure-pipeline.yml add --legacy-peer-deps to the npm install command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).